# Analytics dashboard in Python

Tags: python, data-visualization, analytics, dashboard

please consider the following:

### Introduction

I am a data scientist and I need to present results of my apps with "advanced" charts to users and stakeholders.

What I would like to have is a python-based "analytics dashboard" I can easily customize and that users can easily access and export as reports in PDF/HTML. 
Ideally, it should not require knowing or using javascript or other web languages as I do not have the time nor the expertise to make them work.

I ruled out BI frameworks as my BI colleagues have confirmed that the charts I need would require too much customization if done in the available BI frameworks and, at the same time, they would not exploit the drill-down capabilities of BI tools.

### Current state

I have been using plotnine and jupyter notebooks so far.

The approach works well but I have been hitting at some limitations:

- Jupyter notebooks are files which tie together code, data and interface. I would like to have more separation among those. For example, being able to load data, run the notebook and save it to a report without changing the notebook itself.
- Jupyter notebooks  provide limited GUI control capabilities.
  There are extensions such as ipywidgets (which I tried) and [appmode](https://github.com/oschuett/appmode) that make them more app-like but I am not sure whether it is worth to use these
  extensions or move to a "real" web-app development framework.
- I love the grammar of graphics of plotnine/ggplot but I need to further customize the layout and have interactive charts. Currently I cannot obtain interactive charts from plotnine.

### QUESTIONS

I have evaluated some alternatives (see next section) but I am a bit lost.

I would like to know

- if anyone had a similar problem like mine
- what would they recommend as solution

TIA

---

---

### Alternatives I have considered

#### [Dash and Plotly](https://plot.ly/products/dash/)

PRO:

- Plotly&Dash  should be able to provide the charting and web-app capabilities I need

CONS:

- have to write the static part of the web interface as dash html object
- dash could be incompatible with some javascript libraries. For example, in jupyter I use latex to describe the formulas of some kpis. There seems to be an [issue](https://community.plot.ly/t/mathjax-in-dash/6653) with using latex and mathjax in dash . Indeed, I could not get it to render correctly.
- I wish there was a tutorial helping translating plotnine/ggplot2 charts into plotly.py format (e.g. facets, layouts..).The current documentation seems bit lacking in regard.

#### [Altair](https://altair-viz.github.io/)

PRO:

- interactive charts with grammar of graphics

CONS:

- likely less customizable than plotly
- provides only charts, no support for customizing layouts and user interfaces

### Markdown report generation

There are some markdown-based reporting tools like [Pwave](http://mpastell.com/pweave/) that work as Rmarkdown. I could generate a report template and then export it to html

PRO:

- separate format, data and code.
- use markdown

CONS:

- no interactive GUI, which could be useful for users if they wanted control the charts and data to show or analyse
- I am not sure at the moment they can handle charts generated with plotting libraries

Comment: Note: [Is tool x versus tool y a fair question?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/69/185)